# Different behavior of float32/float64 numpy variables

Tags: python, numpy

after googling a while, I'm posting here for help.

I have two float64 variables returned from a function.
Both of them are apparently 1:

```
>>> x, y = somefunc()
>>> print x,y
>>> if x < 1 :   print "x < 1"
>>> if y < 1 :   print "y < 1"
1.0  1.0
y < 1
```

Behavior changes when variables are defined float32, in which case the 'y<1' statement doesn't appear.

I tried setting

```
np.set_printoptions(precision=10)
```

expecting to see the differences between variables but even so, both of them appear as 1.0 when printed.

I am a bit confused at this point. 
Is there a way to visualize the difference of these float64 numbers?
Can "if/then" be used reliably to check float64 numbers?

Thanks
Trevarez

Comment: I don't understand your question. Obviously the error is in the printed representation where `y` is less than one ni the `float64` case, and is equal(or greater) to `1` when using `float32` due to rounding errors. When dealing with floating point values you whould *never* use equal comparisons. Fix a minimum error(for example `epsilon=1e-16` or smaller/bigger depending on the application) and do `if abs(number - 1) < epsilon: # number is sufficiently close to 1 to be considered as 1`.

Comment: @Bakuriu you can post this as an answer... your pretty much explained what is going on

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The printed values *are not correct*. In your case `y` is smaller than `1` when using `float64` and bigger or equal to `1` when using `float32`. this is expected since rounding errors depend on the size of the `float`.

To avoid this kind of problems, when dealing with floating point numbers you should always decide a "minimum error", usually called `epsilon` and, instead of comparing for equality, checking whether the result is at most distant `epsilon` from the target value:

```
In [13]: epsilon = 1e-11

In [14]: number = np.float64(1) - 1e-16

In [15]: target = 1

In [16]: abs(number - target) < epsilon   # instead of number == target
Out[16]: True
```

In particular, `numpy` already provides `np.allclose` which can be useful to compare arrays for equality given a certain tolerance. It works even when the arguments aren't arrays(e.g. `np.allclose(1 - 1e-16, 1) -> True`).

Note however than `numpy.set_printoptions` doesn't affect how `np.float32`/`64` are printed. It affects only how *arrays* are printed:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: np.float(1) - 1e-16
Out[2]: 0.9999999999999999

In [3]: np.array([1 - 1e-16])
Out[3]: array([ 1.])

In [4]: np.set_printoptions(precision=16)

In [5]: np.array([1 - 1e-16])
Out[5]: array([ 0.9999999999999999])

In [6]: np.float(1) - 1e-16
Out[6]: 0.9999999999999999
```

Also note that doing `print y` or evaluating `y` in the interactive interpreter gives different results:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: np.float(1) - 1e-16
Out[2]: 0.9999999999999999

In [3]: print(np.float64(1) - 1e-16)
1.0
```

The difference is that `print` calls `str` while evaluating calls `repr`:

```
In [9]: str(np.float64(1) - 1e-16)
Out[9]: '1.0'

In [10]: repr(np.float64(1) - 1e-16)
Out[10]: '0.99999999999999989'
```

Comment: Thank you Bakuriu,
it was quite a comprehensive answer that clarify my doubts.

Comment: I was just wondering what is the point of Numpy providing functions as "numpy.where" without a warning on these subtleties on floats?

From the documentation, it follows that can be used directly with floats without concerning about precision issues:

    >>> x = np.arange(9.).reshape(3, 3)
    >>> x[np.where( x > 3.0 )] 
    array([ 4.,  5.,  6.,  7.,  8.])

Comment: @Trevarez It's *not* a problem with numpy. It's a problem with *any* floating point computation. This is something you *ought* to know(see for example [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)). If you want to check where the values are bigger than `3.0`, up to a certain precision you can simply subtract the epsilon first(i.e. `x[np.where((x - epsilon) > 3.0)]`).

Comment: Great article. I think I finally understood the scope of the "problem". Thank you again for your explanations.

Comment: Note: you should use `np.allclose(value, other_value)`. Do not define your own arbitrary epsilon value.

Answer (score 1):

```
In [26]: x  = numpy.float64("1.000000000000001")

In [27]: print x, repr(x)
1.0 1.0000000000000011
```

In other words, you are plagued by loss of precision in `print` statement. The value is very slightly different than `1`.

Comment: see, `print` outputs 11 significant digits and float64 has 15 or so.

Answer (score 0):

Following the advices provided here I summarize the answers in this way:

To make comparisons between floats, the programmer has to define a minimum distance (eps) for them to be considered different (eps=1e-12, for example). Doing so, the conditions should be written like this:

```
Instead of (x>a), use (x-a)>eps
Instead of (x<a), use (a-x)>eps
Instead of (x==a), use abs(x-a)<eps
```

This doesn't apply to comparison between integer numbers since difference between them is fixed to 1.

Hope it helps others as it helped me.